# Enable export as pdf inside Workbook_BeforePrint Cancel

Tags: vba, pdf, if-statement, printing, export

it seems my *"Workbook_BeforePrint(Cancel As Boolean)"* is stopping me from exporting to PDF. I have found that if I remove this sub, PDF export works, but I'd like to keep my "fixes" before print.

Is there a way to rewrite my code to handle export to pdf?

A) To ignore the "Before print cancel" on export (no after effects on PDF)

or

B) Make the code work for export, retaining the after effects my code adds

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforePrint(Cancel As Boolean)
    Application.Volatile True
    Cancel = True

    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

   'My code

    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ActivePrinter displays the current printer name (something like Canon MP230 series auf Ne03:). When exporting to pdf the active printer changes accordingly (at my current station: Foxit Reader PDF Printer auf Ne01:).

So assuming your pdf-printer is foxit, you could use the following code:

```
...
if (Left(ActivePrinter, 5) <> "Foxit") then
    'regular printing, therefore execute your code
else
    'pdf-priner, therefore do something else (or nothing)
end if
...
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll personalize from there :)